# Vertical tabbed content with position sticky

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am not sure why position sticky is not working here:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn2Qw/7178/)

```
#tabs ul {
  position: sticky;
}
```

Since it's too much content to be scrolled, I need help in making the menu sticky, but just when you are in vertical tabs, then I don't need it to be sticky anymore.

Comment: position sticky is experimental and may not work in all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.  If you are using jquery, there is a [plugin called waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) that is really easy to use

Comment: It's always IE or Edge ruining everyones good time, isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not used any position value `top`.

So use `top:0` or any other value to the `#tabs ul`

```
#tabs ul {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/nn2Qw/7179/)**